LanguageExt - Error trying to Match on a method that returns TryAsync<Unit>
I am using a method in a library that returns a TryAsync<Unit> (dumb stupid implementation to show the signature)...
public TryAsync<Unit> DoLibraryStuffAsync() =>
  TryAsync(unit);

I want to call this, and return a Task<Either<string, Unit>>, where the string would contain the error message. I have got as far as this...
private async Task<Either<string, Unit>> DoMyStuffAsync() =>
  (await DoLibraryStuffAsync())
    .Match(_ => unit,
      ex => $"Ex: {ex.Message}");

However, this gives a compiler error on both of the branches in Match...

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Hovering over Match, I can see that the compiler has picked up on the overload that takes Funcs, so I would have expected to be able to return either a string or unit...

Anyone able to explain what I'm doing wrong, and how I fix it?

Whilst I can't offer a full explanation of the problem (as I don't completely understand it myself!), I can suggest how to fix it.
I think the problem is that the compiler can't work out exactly what you're returning (no, I'm not sure why either!), but if you make it explicit, I think it will work...
private async Task<Either<string, Unit>> DoMyStuffAsync() =>
  (await DoLibraryStuffAsync())
    .Match(_ => Right<string, Unit>(unit),
      ex => $"Ex: {ex.Message}");

I would hope that someone can come along and explain to both of us why we need to do this, but at least this should get you going.
Update
OK, I discussed this with someone who understands this stuff better than I do (which is most people actually), and I think I have an idea why you got a compiler error.
Consider the following silly method...
Either<string, int> Jim() {
  Random r = new();
  return r.Next() % 100 > 50 ? 1 : "jim";
}

This compiles without needing to cast explicitly to an Either because both types that can be returned are in the same bit of code (ie the return statement).
In your code, the two Funcs that you passed to Match were in separate pieces of code, so the compiler couldn't put them together and work out what the return type should be. I think this is because, although we humans can understand that both Funcs passed Match produce a return value for the same method, the compiler doesn't know that. It has no idea what Match does.
Not sure that's completely clear, but I think it gives some idea why you needed to cast at least one of the return values.

Thanks so much! Now you mention it, I think I have bumped into this before. I'd love to know why we need it though

@AvrohomYisroel highly likely this happens due to overload resolution selecting Match overload accepting Action<T> so it makes lambda _ => unit passed to it an invalid one (which is "fixed" by changing the lambda to _ => { var i = unit; }). Use just use ToEither (see my answer).

@GuruStron My first thought was that the compiler had inferred the Action overload, but as I pointed out in my question, hovering over Match shows that it picked up the Func overload, which is why I was (and still am) confused. Will look at your answer tomorrow, thanks

@AvrohomYisroel 1) it does show Action overload for me (.NET 8, latest Rider - picture) 2) the suggested "fix" works for me.  Either way, just use the  ToEither =)

@GuruStron That's weird. I wonder why Rider shows it as using the Action overload, whereas VS shows it as using the Func one? The project in question is actually .NET7, but I just created a new .NET8 app and tried it there, and VS still showed it as using the Action overload,  Sounds like a bug to me!

@GuruStron I just created a new app in Rider and pasted in exactly the same code, and indeed it showed the Action overload. Definitely sounds like a bug.

@AvrohomYisroel I would argue that the "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" error generated by the compiler shows that the Action overload is actually selected (fiddle with error).

@GuruStron No need to argue, I'm sure you're right! I'm just concerned that VS showed me the wrong overload.

@AvrohomYisroel "I'm sure you're right!" - but I'm not that sure myself though =)) Are you using ReSharper in the VS?

@GuruStron I am using R#, but I get the same if I disable it, so it looks like it's VS that's showing the wrong info

I would argue that you should consider using ToEither (has versions accepting both Try and TryAsync):
async Task<Either<string, Unit>> DoMyStuffAsync() =>
     await DoLibraryStuffAsync().ToEither(ex => $"Ex: {ex.Message}");


Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any reason to use ToEither over the explicit cast mentioned in the other answer? They both add about the same noise to the code, and I was wondering if there were any technical differences. Thanks again.

@AvrohomYisroel based on the sample provided in the accepted answer I would argue that ToEither is much more readable. And arguably more idiomatic.

OK, thanks for the reply
